# jest test in node.js is failing showing Matcher error

Tags: node.js, regex, jestjs

Jest test is failing. Matcher error: received value must have a length property whose value must be a number

```
Received has type:  object
Received has value: {}
```

but object has a value and it is not {}

index.js file

```
const fs = require('fs');

select('company')

async function select(selector)   {

await fs.readFile('./content.html', 'utf8',    function (err, data) {
 if (err) throw err;

 regexForIds = new RegExp(/<([^\s]+).*?id="company".*?>(.+?)<\/\1>/gi);

 matches = data.match(regexForIds);

 const obj = {
   length:  matches.length
 };

 return obj

});

}

module.exports = select;
```

index.js file

```
const select = require('./');
test('select supports ids', () => {
  expect(select('#company')).toHaveLength(1);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- `fs.readFile` doesn't return a promise, so `await fs.readFile` won't work.
- `select` is an async function and it doesn't return an obj, so `expect(select('#company')).toHaveLength(1)` won't work either.

You can fix the first point by wrapping `fs.readFile` with a Promise (note that there are other ways of fixing this, like using [promisify](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v8.x/docs/api/util.html#util_util_promisify_original)):

```
const fs = require("fs");

async function select(selector) {
  const obj = await new Promise((res, rej) => {
    fs.readFile("./content.html", "utf8", function(err, data) {
      if (err) rej(err);

      regexForIds = new RegExp(/<([^\s]+).*?id="company".*?>(.+?)<\/\1>/gi);

      matches = data.match(regexForIds);

      const obj = {
        length: matches.length,
      };
      res(obj);
    });
  });

  return obj;
}

module.exports = select;
```

To fix the second point, you need to change the test slightly, by adding an `await` before calling `select`:

```
const select = require("./");
test("select supports ids", async () => {
  expect(await select("#company")).toHaveLength(1);
});
```

You will probably have to change the location of `./content.html` depending on how you run your tests.